# iOS 7 resize issue of UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

In my application I have to resize `UIDatePicker` *(with mode `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime`)* and add it in custom view it's working very well in iOS 6  but issue occur in iOS 7.

When i resize `UIDatePicker` in iOS 7 with same code then days name like sunday, monday,.. etc not displaying clearly/fully.

Check following video for more clear picture.

[image]

So how can i fixed it in iOS 7?

Comment: [You cannot customize the appearance of date pickers.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker)

Comment: On a related note, I had some luck with Content Compression Priority of 200 when doing this with autolayout. However, I am not sure if this exactly matches the above case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @A-Live is right, you can't change the appearance of UIDatePicker. Instead if you want to resize it you should go with a tricky way. You can set it's transform to resize it.

```
datePicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
```

It will scale down datePicker width & height.